# using match to get data from a closed worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get data from numerous closed worksheets and bring it into my current worksheet. The issue us that the cell where the data is found in different worksheets is not consistent. For example, say I want to get the profits from 3 different files (File 1, 2 and 3), in file 1 it may be in row 1, File 2 in row 2 and file 3 in row 3.

I have tried to use the worksheet.match formula and the with cells .formulae but neither method seems to work. I need to try and not open all the other worksheets as there are 400 of them.
Please could someone help.

Comment: Hoe do you find the data, ie what are you searching for? And in all 400 closed sheets(books?) each time. Is standardising the closed workbooks (either properly, or by inserting rows using VBA to make your main row the same location an option?

Comment: I have 10 workbooks each of about 2.4 Mb.  The first worksheet in each is similar but not identical.  On my 2.1GHz laptop, 40 repeats of a loop that opens and closes these 10 files takes 188 seconds.  Searching for a piece of movable text before closing each workbook bring the duration up to 190 seconds.  You have to transfer data which will take some time but, if this is a daily task, I do not see four minutes, say, as excessive.  You have told us nothing about your the nature of the data you are seeking and what you want done with it.  How do you expect us to be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ADO to query the closed workbooks and import their data into the current workbook rather than trying to deal with a bunch of messy formulas. You can customize the SQL query for each indivdual workbook store all of your SQL strings in an array so that you could do a nested loop and query n workbooks. If that sounds like something you'd like to look into but need some help on the code then I'd be glad to write up an example.